# Array_map when elements are shuffled

Tags: php, shuffle, array-map

I have this array (it's just a part of it). 6 = question ID, optionIDs = possible answers.

```
Array
 (
    [3] => Array
        (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 16
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 14
                        [isCorrect] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 15
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 17
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 16
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 15
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 17
                        [isCorrect] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [optionID] => 14
                        [isCorrect] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I'm trying to merge redundant questions (6 and 6) with array_map:

```
    $unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $quizQuestionArray)));
```

And it works as long as optionIDs are in the same order. But in some cases (like here) they are shuffled (16,14,15,17) (16,15,17,14). Is there a way to keep them shuffled and remove duplicate questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_map-serialize is a pretty crude way to deduplicate an array. You should be using something like this instead:

```
$dupeIds = [];
$array = array_filter($array, function ($item) use (&$dupeIds) {
    $keep = !isset($dupeIds[$item[0]]);
    $dupeIds[$item[0]] = true;
    return $keep;
});
```

Comment: This is a really clever solution. +1

Comment: +1. Of course it returns those which should be gone - to get the rest: $remove = !isset($dupeIds[$item[0]]);

Comment: @user3385195 Right, fixed that bug.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort them to the same order before applying you array_map() function. You can use the [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function and supply your own comparison function like this:

```
// Example array
$array = array(
    3 => array(
        0 => 6,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                'optionID' => 16,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
            1 => array(
                'optionID' => 14,
                'isCorrect' => 1
            ),
            2 => array(
                'optionID' => 15,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
            3 => array(
                'optionID' => 17,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
        )
    ),
    7 => array(
        0 => 6,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                'optionID' => 16,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
            1 => array(
                'optionID' => 15,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
            2 => array(
                'optionID' => 17,
                'isCorrect' => 0
            ),
            3 => array(
                'optionID' => 14,
                'isCorrect' => 1
            ),
        )
    )
);

// You can supply parts of an array to uasort()
// uasort() will modify your array but keep your keys.
uasort($array[3][2], 'sort_by_optionid');
uasort($array[7][3], 'sort_by_optionid');

function sort_by_optionid($a, $b) {
    if ($a['optionID'] === $b['optionID']) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($a['optionID'] > $b['optionID']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
// Done.
```

Now the keys are preserved and you can easily array_map() to find the duplicates and then sort again back to the original state according to the keys. E.g. with [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)